# TypeError: categories is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I made my program mad. I was trying to make some adjustments from a previous issue I was having with a unpermitted parameters: :recipe issue I was having. I basically encapsulated attributes within a recipe object to hopefully match what was being sent to the backend due to strong params. I pointed to where those changes were made. Whether that being resolved is contingent on the work around for this current issue now. After making some changes I keep getting this **TypeError: categories is undefined** after I adjusted my action type for my dispatch payload on the frontend using redux.

```
switch(action.type){
        case 'Add_Recipe':
            const recipe = {
               recipe:{   <-----I encapsulated everything within a recipe value and recipe as my key
                name: action.name,
                ingredients: action.ingredients,
                chef_name: action.chef_name,
                origin: action.origin,
                // categoryId: action.categoryId,
                category: action.category
               }
            }

            return{
                ...state,
                recipes: [...state.recipes, recipe],
            }
       
        default:
            return state
        
    }
}
```

And to make sure I everything was consistent with this change I also changed my initial state and setState in my RecipeInput component.
**Note: I left event handlers out on purpose for this code snippet**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import  Categories  from './Categories.js'



class RecipeInput extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props)
        this.state = {
            recipe:{  <-----I encapsulated everything within a recipe value and recipe as my key
            category: [],
            name:'',
            ingredients: '',
            chef_name: '',
            origin: ''
            }
        }
        this.handleNameChange.bind(this)
        this.handleOriginChange.bind(this)
        this.handleChefChange.bind(this)
        this.handleIngChange.bind(this)


        
    }

    

    componentDidMount(){
        let initialCats = [];
        const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
        const CATEGOREIS_URL =`${BASE_URL}/categories`
        fetch(CATEGOREIS_URL)
        .then(resp => resp.json())
        .then(data => {
            
            initialCats = data.map((category) => {
                return category
            })
            console.log(initialCats)
                this.setState({
                    category: initialCats,
                })   
            });
    }


    handleSubmit = (event) =>{
        event.preventDefault();
        this.props.postRecipes(this.state)
        this.setState({
        recipe:{   <-----I encapsulated everything within a recipe value and recipe as my key
        name:'',
        ingredients: '',
        chef_name: '',
        origin: ''
        }
     })
    }

    
        

    render(){
        return(
            <div>
                <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                    <Categories category={this.state.category}/>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Recipe Name:</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.name} onChange={this.handleNameChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Country Origin:</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.origin} onChange={this.handleOriginChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Chef Name:</label>
                    <input type='text' value={this.state.chef_name} onChange={this.handleChefChange} />
                    </div>
                    <div>
                    <label for='name'>Ingredients:</label>
                    <textarea value={this.state.ingredients} onChange={this.handleIngChange} />
                    </div>
                    <input value='submit' type='submit'/>
                </form>
            </div>
        )
    }


 


}

export default RecipeInput
```

I also made necessary changes in my postRecipe action

```
export const postRecipes = (recipe)=>{
    const BASE_URL = `http://localhost:10524`
    const RECIPES_URL =`${BASE_URL}/recipes`

    
    const config = {
        method: "POST",
        body:JSON.stringify(recipe),
        headers: {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-type": "application/json"
     }
    }
    //category field
    return(dispatch)=>{
    fetch(RECIPES_URL,config)
    .then(response => 
    response.json())
    .then(resp => {
        dispatch({
            type: 'Add_Recipe',
            payload:{
              recipe:{  <-----I encapsulated everything within a recipe value and recipe as my key
                category:resp.category,
                name: resp.name,
                ingredients: resp.ingredients,
                chef_name: resp.chef_name,
                origin: resp.origin,
                // categoryId: resp.categoryId 
                }
            }
        })
    })
    //.then(response => <Recipe />)
      .catch((error) => console.log.error(error))

    }
    
    
}
```

After making those changes I started getting the **TypeError: categories is undefined** error in my Categories component.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

class Categories extends Component{
    

    render(){
        let categories = this.props.category
        //I am getting screamed at for categories being undefined after previous changes
        let optionItems = categories.map((cat,index) =>
            <option key={index}>{cat.category}</option>
        )


        return (
            <div>
                <select>
                    {optionItems}
                </select>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Categories
```

The type error started happening after encapsulated everything as recipe as my key and all the other attributes as the values. Can somebody help point where my broke at after making changes?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are updating your state from the fetch with undefined data:

```
this.setState({
   category: initialCats
})
```

You've encapsulated the category property inside the recipe object. So it should be something like:

```
this.setState({
   recipe: {
     ...this.state.recipe,
     category: initialCats,
   }
})
```

In your `Categories` component return you could also do this for example to show categories are loading:

```
return (
            <div>
                <select>
                    {this.props.category.length ? optionItems : <p>Loading...</p>}
                </select>
            </div>
        )
```